# How to fix 'The memory could not be written' error?

Tags: c, file

I tried to do the **Reading/Writing structs to files** with the help of a youtube course. I wrote the same code just with the names changed. When I compile the code `gcc -o _main _main.c`, i get this error message:

> The instruction at 0x00000000765AF391 referenced memory at 0x000000000000000F. The memory could not be written.

I'm wondering what the problem is, i think it's a **memory leak** but i'm not sure. If someone knows a solution to my problem, I would ask him to write it **with some explanation**.

*Code:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Client {
    char userFirstName[15];
    char userLastName[15];
    char userPassword[20];
    float userBankMoney;
    float userHandMoney;
} Client;

const char* WORKER_FORMAT_IN = "(%[^,], %[^,], %d)\n";
const char* WORKER_FORMAT_OUT = "(%s, %s, %d)\n";

typedef struct Worker {
    char workerFirstName[15];
    char workerLasttName[15];
    int workerCode[5];
} Worker;

//>>>FUNCTIONS PROTOTYPES<<<//
void printOptions();
void loginAsWorker();
void createAccount();
void payment();
void withdrawal();
void moneyTransfer();
void balanceReview(double balance);

int main() {
    Worker worker1 = {
        .workerFirstName = "Matija",
        .workerLasttName = "Davidovic",
        .workerCode = 12345
    };
    Worker worker2;
    
    FILE* worker_file;
    worker_file = fopen("worker.dat", "w+");
    if(worker_file == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(worker_file, WORKER_FORMAT_OUT, worker1.workerFirstName, worker1.workerLasttName, worker1.workerCode);
    fseek(worker_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(worker_file, WORKER_FORMAT_IN, worker2.workerFirstName, 15, &worker2.workerLasttName, &worker2.workerCode);    
    return 0;
}
```

I want to find out what the problem is in the code and understand a little more about the FILES in C programming language.

Comment: "*i think it's a **memory leak***" -- more likely it's an invalid pointer.  Address `0xF`?

Comment: `worker2.workerFirstName, 15, &worker2.workerLasttName` : you have 15 AKA 0xF in your list of arguments of scanf as a pointer... you probably got warnings about this but chose to ignore them

Comment: Your scanf format string only has 3 conversion operators. Why do you have 4 arguments after it? What is the `15` supposed to be for?

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `&` before a string when using it as a destination argument in `scanf()`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why the course used `&` before `workers2.`, but both with and without it, when I start the code, it enters the correct **Name** and **Last Name**, but sets a completely **different** value for the code.